# email connector doesnt work

Tags: business-process-management, business-connector, bonita

I've tried several tutorials/solved questions but the email connector doesn't seem to work for me. any advice anyone ? i've added a new runtime variable `_JPI_VM_OPTIONS = Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` but nothing seems to work i never receive the mail. I'm trying to send a mail to my personal email, and when i open my inbox, nothing. also when i logged in as administrator, i found the email connector in failed tasks. so my problem is whatever i do, my email connector doesn't work. as i said i've tried several web tutorial /youtube tutorial and nothing seems to work for me. I've configured the proxy when i installed bonita. i've tried also with my company smtp(besides gmail smtp) and it doesn't work.

here is my bonita engine log :

```
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.engine.log.technical.TechnicalLoggerSLF4JImpl log
INFO: THREAD_ID=57 | HOSTNAME=G3127 | TENANT_ID=1 | The user has executed the task [name = , display name = , id = <20002>, parent process instance = <1001>, root process instance = <1001>, process definition = <5266138508294277224>]
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: charset UTF-8
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: message test test denial
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: html true
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: subject test
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: bcc null
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: cc null
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: to anwarbenkassou90@gmail.com
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: from anwarbenkassou90@gmail.com
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: userName anwarbenkassou90@gmail.com
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: starttlsSupport false
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: sslSupport false
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: smtpPort 465
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: smtpHost smtp.gmail.com
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: replyTo null
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameters
INFO: password ******
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameters
INFO: Headers null
13 avr. 2015 15:43:00 org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector logInputParameter
INFO: headers []
13 avr. 2015 15:43:03 org.bonitasoft.engine.log.technical.TechnicalLoggerSLF4JImpl log
GRAVE: THREAD_ID=97 | HOSTNAME=G3127 | TENANT_ID=1 | The work [ExecuteConnectorOfActivity: flowNodeInstanceId = 20004, connectorDefinitionName = EmailDenial] failed. The failure will be handled.
13 avr. 2015 15:43:03 org.bonitasoft.engine.log.technical.TechnicalLoggerSLF4JImpl log
GRAVE: THREAD_ID=97 | HOSTNAME=G3127 | TENANT_ID=1 | org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.exception.SConnectorException : "PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID=5266138508294277224 | PROCESS_NAME=RMA | PROCESS_VERSION=1.0 | PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=1001 | ROOT_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=1001 | FLOW_NODE_DEFINITION_ID=-7928415675851615386 | FLOW_NODE_INSTANCE_ID=20004 | FLOW_NODE_NAME=Email Denial | CONNECTOR_DEFINITION_IMPLEMENTATION_CLASS_NAME=EmailDenial | CONNECTOR_INSTANCE_ID=20001 | org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com"
org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.exception.SConnectorException: PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID=5266138508294277224 | PROCESS_NAME=RMA | PROCESS_VERSION=1.0 | PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=1001 | ROOT_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID=1001 | FLOW_NODE_DEFINITION_ID=-7928415675851615386 | FLOW_NODE_INSTANCE_ID=20004 | FLOW_NODE_NAME=Email Denial | CONNECTOR_DEFINITION_IMPLEMENTATION_CLASS_NAME=EmailDenial | CONNECTOR_INSTANCE_ID=20001 | org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.impl.ConnectorServiceImpl.executeConnectorInClassloader(ConnectorServiceImpl.java:332)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.impl.ConnectorServiceImpl.executeConnector(ConnectorServiceImpl.java:150)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorServiceDecorator.executeConnector(ConnectorServiceDecorator.java:111)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.work.ExecuteConnectorWork.work(ExecuteConnectorWork.java:125)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.work.failurewrapping.TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.work(TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.java:42)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.work.failurewrapping.TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.work(TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.java:42)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.work.failurewrapping.TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.work(TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.java:42)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.work.failurewrapping.TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.work(TxInHandleFailureWrappingWork.java:42)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.execution.work.FailureHandlingBonitaWork.work(FailureHandlingBonitaWork.java:66)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.work.BonitaWork.run(BonitaWork.java:56)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.work.SequenceRunnableExecutor.innerRun(SequenceRunnableExecutor.java:47)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.work.BonitaRunnable.run(BonitaRunnable.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.impl.ConnectorExecutorImpl.execute(ConnectorExecutorImpl.java:127)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.impl.ConnectorServiceImpl.executeConnectorInClassloader(ConnectorServiceImpl.java:324)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.impl.ConnectorExecutorImpl.getValue(ConnectorExecutorImpl.java:151)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.impl.ConnectorExecutorImpl.execute(ConnectorExecutorImpl.java:121)
... 15 more
Caused by: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.exception.SConnectorException: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.impl.SConnectorAdapter.execute(SConnectorAdapter.java:72)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.impl.ConnectorExecutorImpl$ExecuteConnectorCallable.call(ConnectorExecutorImpl.java:203)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.impl.ConnectorExecutorImpl$ExecuteConnectorCallable.call(ConnectorExecutorImpl.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
Caused by: org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.ConnectorException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector.executeBusinessLogic(EmailConnector.java:473)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.connector.AbstractConnector.execute(AbstractConnector.java:77)
at org.bonitasoft.engine.core.connector.impl.SConnectorAdapter.execute(SConnectorAdapter.java:70)
... 7 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Unknown SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1970)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:642)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.bonitasoft.connectors.email.EmailConnector.executeBusinessLogic(EmailConnector.java:471)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:319)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:233)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1938)
... 16 more
```

thank you :)

Comment: You should probably take some time to fix the spelling and grammar in the question. You're not texting on a cell phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you work in a company that use a proxy, it's is mostly possible that the email is blocked by this proxy. 
If this is the issue, you need to use the smtp of your company or ask to the administrator of the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the log entry below, the Bonita XP (or Portal, dependig on your Bonita version) cannot reach the host `smtp.gmail.com`. Probable cause is a missing proxy configuration or a firewall rule prohibiting the access.

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: smtp.gmail.com
```